# Android Private API, Invocation failure

Tags: android, dalvik, android-context

I need, for my app, some private APIs and I found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117124429/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/07/access-internal-classes-in-android.html). So I tried to do reflection and invoke the method getDefault as follows:

```
Class ActivityManagerNative = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
Class IActivityManager = Class.forName("android.app.IActivityManager");

Method getDefault = ActivityManagerNative.getMethod("getDefault", null);
Object am = IActivityManager.cast(getDefault.invoke(ActivityManagerNative, null));
```

It worked nicely. Then I made one jar and one apk. I'm just trying to run apk in the terminal with am start and also to run jar with dalvikvm in terminal. The difference between both is that .jar file doesn't work. It loads successfully `ActivityManagerNative` and getDefault but not the invocation. The Exception is something with `getContextObject`. What does it mean? Can somebody help me?

Comment: How do you start your apk/jar? Have you tried the apk on a device/emulator?

Comment: on my device(motorola milestone) i rooted my device and I start with dalvikvm -cp /path to jar com.and.test and apk with am start -n com.and.Test